# QGIS 2.4.0 Setting raster layer to singlebandpseudocolor using minimum and maximum raster values

Tags: qgis, raster, metadata, color-ramp, colormap

I am using QGIS Chugiak 2.4.0, and I have some code in which I want to:

1. Add raster layer to map canvas
2. Look for the minimum and maximum raster value
3. Apply singleband pseudocolor render type for the min max values
4. Use a nice color map (e.g. RdYlBl)
5. Update the map canvas/legend with these settings

I found some code in the PyGis cookbook as shown below:

```
layer = QgsRasterLayer(file, layername)
rastermin = ?
rastermax = ?
layer.setDrawingStyle("SingleBandPseudoColor")
layer.setColorShadingAlgorithm(QgsRasterLayer.ColorRampShader)
lst = [ QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(rastermin, QColor(0,255,0)), QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(rastermax, QColor(255,255,0)) ]
fcn = rlayer.rasterShader().rasterShaderFunction()
fcn.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.INTERPOLATED)
fcn.setColorRampItemList(lst)
```

First of all, I don't know how to retrieve the minimum and maximum values of the raster layer.
Secondly, it seems that `setColorShadingAlgorithm` does not work in QGIS Chugiak 2.4.0.
Thirdly, instead of using the `QColor(0,255,0)` I'd like to use one of the nice existing colormaps in QGIS, e.g.RdYlBl.

Does anyone have any clue how to solve this?

Best Regards,
Wilco

Answer (score 1):

I am new to PyQGIS and was actually looking for a solution to the same question: why is `setColorShadingAlgorithm` not working. However I do have an answer for your first question, how to calculate the min and the max values of a raster layer. There's for sure an easier and cleaner way to do it, but I've been doing it using the `gdal` library:

```
from osgeo import gdal

raster = "raster.tif"

# load raster
gdalData = gdal.Open(raster)
# get number of bands
bands = gdalData.RasterCount
# process the raster
for i in xrange(1, bands + 1):
    band = gdalData.GetRasterBand(i)
    # fetch max and min
    min = band.GetMinimum()
    max = band.GetMaximum()
    if min is None or max is None:
        (min,max) = band.ComputeRasterMinMax(1)
    print 'Min=%.3f, Max=%.3f' % (min,max)
```

Comment: +1 for working example. To simplify your script use *.GetMinimum()*, from http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html search for `min = band.GetMinimum()`

Comment: thanks a lot! I've edited the script and it looks much nicer now

Answer (score 0):

The second half of your question is answered in xunilk's answer to this [GIS StackExchange post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134435/what-is-the-replacement-for-setcolorshadingalgorithm-in-qgis-2-6).

I have combined the two into the following Python script, which finds the min and max of the raster and applies the resulting color ramp:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from osgeo import gdal

# use PyQT QFileInfo to get the base name of the raster file
rPath = '/path/to/raster.tif'
fileInfo = QFileInfo(rPath)
rLabel = fileInfo.baseName()

# use the file name as the label for raster
rLayer = QgsRasterLayer(rPath,rLabel)

# add the layer to the map
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rLayer)

# load raster
gdalData = gdal.Open(rPath)
# get number of bands
bands = gdalData.RasterCount
# process the raster
for i in xrange(1, bands + 1):
    band = gdalData.GetRasterBand(i)
    # fetch max and min
    min = band.GetMinimum()
    max = band.GetMaximum()
    if min is None or max is None:
        (min,max) = band.ComputeRasterMinMax(1)

range = max-min
add = range//2
int = min + add

colDic={'red':'#ff0000', 'yellow':'#ffff00','blue':'#0000ff'}

valueList =[min, int, max]

lst = [ QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[0], QColor(colDic['blue'])), \
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[1], QColor(colDic['yellow'])), \
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[2], QColor(colDic['red']))]

myRasterShader = QgsRasterShader()
myColorRamp = QgsColorRampShader()

myColorRamp.setColorRampItemList(lst)
myColorRamp.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.INTERPOLATED)
myRasterShader.setRasterShaderFunction(myColorRamp)

myPseudoRenderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(\
    rLayer.dataProvider(), rLayer.type(),  myRasterShader)

rLayer.setRenderer(myPseudoRenderer)

# Refresh the canvas and the legend
rLayer.triggerRepaint()
iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(rLayer)
```