# What is replacement for setColorShadingAlgorithm in QGIS 2.6?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, rendering

I have been struggling with setting the `colorshadingalgorithm` for a raster layer in QGIS with no success for the past few days. The QGIS cookbook seems to be pretty outdated.

The code that I am using is:

```
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
app = QgsApplication([], True)

plotdir = r"/home/qgis_prac/"
inShp = r"/home/qgis_prac/shps/Peru_Boundary.shp"
uri = r"/home/qgis_prac/tiffs/Peru_DEM.tif"
layer = QgsRasterLayer(uri, "Peru_DEM")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
layer.setDrawingStyle('SingleBandPseudoColor') # main thing goes wrong here, I think
layer.ColorShadingAlgorithm(QgsRasterLayer.PseudoColorShader) # seems to do nothng. Also the setColorShadingAlgorithm is deprecated

if hasattr(layer, "setCacheImage"):
  layer.setCacheImage(None)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

The code goes on....

My problem is that when the script runs, it gives me an empty map with no entries in the legend. If I use the grayband shader then it works, also for the `PalettedColor` (but some cells are assigned colors).

What I need is some replacement or work around setting the `ColorShadingAlgorithm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The QGIS cookbook is pretty outdated but is possible to find out the solution  when the class methods of **QgsColorRampShader**, **QgsRasterShader** and **QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer** ('setDrawingStyle' does not work) are explored at the Python Console. I used the following code to convert a raster with a **SingleBandGray** render type (minimum value = 1323, maximum value = 3556) in a **SingleBandPseudoColor** render type with my own **ColorRampShader**.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

layer=iface.activeLayer()

min=1323
max =3556
range =max-min
add=range//2
int =min + add

colDic={'red':'#ff0000', 'yellow':'#ffff00','blue':'#0000ff'}

valueList =[min, int, max]

lst = [ QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[0], QColor(colDic['red'])), \
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[1], QColor(colDic['yellow'])), \
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[2], QColor(colDic['blue']))]

myRasterShader = QgsRasterShader()
myColorRamp = QgsColorRampShader()

myColorRamp.setColorRampItemList(lst)
myColorRamp.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.INTERPOLATED)
myRasterShader.setRasterShaderFunction(myColorRamp)

myPseudoRenderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(\
    layer.dataProvider(), layer.type(),  myRasterShader)

layer.setRenderer(myPseudoRenderer)

iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)
```

Initial state:

[image]

After running the code at the Python Console:

[image]